# youtube-dl fix for post-defunct status legitimate users (2024 going forward)

Tags: youtube

I need to get `youtube-dl` operational (or a fork, for instance yt-dlp et.al.) to salvage videos that will be removed from the cloud at a later date. Is there a current fix that will make it work again? Here's what I already know and could find online.

First, `youtube-dl` is a powerful command line tool for downloading videos from Youtube and storing them locally rather than in the cloud. I use to use it all the time for a number of years, up until approximately 2022 or 2023. It required periodic code fixing which could be done with a simple `pip install --upgrade youtube-dl` on a computer with Python.

However, starting in 2020 `youtube-dl` came under attack by governments and institutions around the world. Today, `youtube-dl` is defunct.

However, it's my understanding that it, or forks or derivatives of it are still being used for legitimate and legal purposes. When I go online to find fixes on Google, Duck Duck Go, Yahoo and others all direct me to old discussions that lead users down a rabbit hole of ineffective trouble shooting.

The search sites aren't directing me to a fix, but to old obsolete message threads or useless discussions.

For those who need to use this tool legitimately and legally, (`youtube-dl` et.al.) can they post the fix here for us.

Comment: Have you tried yt-dlp yet? You're aware of it, so presumably you can see it is still being actively developed. I have not used it in the past few months, but it has worked fine in the recent past when I did use it. Your question expends a lot of effort giving unnecessary context, but doesn't indicate any effort on your part, and I'd wager that if you just check out some of those active forks you mention, you'll probably find a functional tool.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it demonstrates OP is already aware of viable alternatives, but has not tried them prior to asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[youtube-dl](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl)
is still being developed on Github with new fixes.

Its last release is
[youtube-dl 2021.12.17](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/releases/tag/2021.12.17)
from 2021, but there are fixes to the sources that date even from the last
few days. You may recompile it using the following instructions:

> If you modify the code, you can run it by executing the `__main__.py` file. To recompile the executable, run `make youtube-dl`.

However, you don't need to recompile if the 2021 release is
still working for you.

---

As regarding the error of
"Unable to extract uploader id", see bug-report
[Unable to extract uploader id #31530](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/31530).

It reports the problem as solved in
[yt-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp),
whose last current release is
[yt-dlp 2024.03.10](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/releases/tag/2024.03.10)
from just a few days ago.

Comment: I'm using --version 2021.12.17 and it was working until around 2022 or 2023.  Now I get: "ERROR: Unable to extract uploader id; please report this . . .

Comment: This error has been fixed, but on yt-dlp. See my update to the answer.

Comment: i'm in the process of checking out yt-dlp on github but in the mean time I noticed the debian repository has: "youtube-dl/oldstable,now 2021.06.06-1 all [installed,automatic]
  downloader of videos from YouTube and other sites"  - - - that version had the uploader id problem too. And, the upgrade from python's pip to 2021.12.17 still had it.  I'm putting that information out their as it might be beneficial to others

Comment: I verified that yt-dlp 2024.03.10 is working now; I'm the original person who posted the question